# How do I generate the so library from Python code and call it in C?

Tags: python, c, nuitka

My goal is to generate the so library from Python code and then call it in C.  Here's how I did it

add.py

```
def add(x, y):
    return x+y
```

using command:
`python -m nuitka --module add.py` and get add.so

using main.c call add.so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main()
{
    void* handle = dlopen("./add.so", RTLD_LAZY);

    if (!handle) {
            fputs (dlerror(), stderr);
            exit(1);
    }

    int (*add)(int a, int b);

    add = dlsym(handle, "add");
    if(dlerror()) {
      perror("dlsym error");
      abort();
    }
    int sum = add(7, 8);
    printf("7+8 = %d\n", sum);

    dlclose(handle);
    return 0;
}
```

then compile main.c with:
`gcc -o main main.c -ldl`
the result is：

> add.so: undefined symbol: PyExc_SystemError

Comment: You're not checking for the successful result of any of those `dl...` functions.

Comment: Also you're doing it the wrong way: Python (Java, C++, PHP, Perl etc) can  call  C-plugin, not the other way around.

Comment: @ThomasJager  Thank you for your feedback, I reedited the problem description to include the return result check for the DL function, and the result.

Comment: @tfxidian Great! Unfortunately, I'm not too familiar with these tools. I don't even know if what you're doing is possible, I would have expected that your main program still needs to be Python compiled to an executable, and that `nuitka --module` just lets you link modules to that.

Answer (score 0):

add the following code can solve "undefined symbol: PyExc_SystemError"

```
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main()                                                                                        
{                                               
   Py_Initialize();
   // ...
}
```

[g++ compiling parameter](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html#compiling-and-linking-under-unix-like-systems)

```bash
/usr/bin/python3.10-config  --ldflags --embed
python3.10-config --cflags

g++ -o main main.cc  -ldl -I/usr/include/python3.10 -I/usr/include/python3.10  -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -g      -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -L/usr/lib/python3.10/config-3.10-x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lpython3.10 -lcrypt -ldl  -lm -lm
```

but I still have problem:

```
nm -gD add.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so |less
```

find

0000000000012430 T PyInit_add

so change code to

```
    add = reinterpret_cast<long (*)(long, long)>(dlsym(handle, "PyInit_add"));
```

still failed, always get different big num:

```
g++ -o main main.cc  -ldl -I/usr/include/python3.10 -I/usr/include/python3.10  -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -g      -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -L/usr/lib/python3.10/config-3.10-x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lpython3.10 -lcrypt -ldl  -lm -lm 
./main
7+8 = 140716692567632
./main
7+8 = 140153746781776
./main
7+8 = 140353451177552
```